# Clicking image in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to click an image that does not have an id.
Using other methods of identification yields an "element can not be found" error or an "element is not selectable" error.

Here's the code:

```
                  <a href="#" class="right-off-canvas-toggle share-menu-trigger"><img src="/assets/images/Icons/Team-Slider-Icon.png" style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:25px;float: right;"></a>

                <div class="notifications">
                  <a href="/dash/6/Dashboard"></a>
                </div>
              </ul>
              <div class="clearboth"></div>
            </nav>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div class="top-container show-for-small mobileHeader">
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
toggle = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('team-toggle')
toggle = browser.find_element_by_class_name('team-toggle')
toggle = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="top-nav"]/ul/a[4]/img')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Using Firefox developer edition, I inspected the element I sought to click.

Under accessibility, I found the relevant graphic, right clicked, and selected "print to JSON". That opened up a new page. I found nodeCssSelector and copied what was listed.

The working code is:

`toggle = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".right-off-canvas-toggle > img:nth-child(1)")
toggle.click()`